# How to update database using `id`?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to update my database using `id`, I have already a database which have their name

Now when i update my database using `WHERE college='1'` it works successfully but when i update my database using `id` it's not working please help, and my database `id=1` for which i'm working for..

here is my source code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Bhawanku","members");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "(".$row['id'].") ".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'];
        }

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE admin SET first_name='Rajendra', last_name='Arora'
WHERE id='$id'");


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**EDITED**

after putting `$id` it's showing an error undefined variable id.. what's that meaning?

Comment: Where exactly is `$id` defined?

Comment: Where are you setting your `$id` variable?

Comment: you have to assign value for $id before update query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` is a number, not a string. Change it to:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE admin SET first_name='Rajendra', last_name='Arora' WHERE id=".$row['id']);
```

**EDIT**
Your `id` is only used inside your loop. Try changing it from `while` to `if`

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin limit 0, 1");
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE admin SET first_name='Rajendra', last_name='Arora' WHERE id=$row['id']");
}
```

Any other way, using `while`, will change all user names in the table.
If you have more that one row in this table you'll need another approach.

Comment: i tried your code but it's giving this error :  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\raj.php on line 11`

Comment: Try writing the `$row['id']` outside the quotes, like in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$id` is not set in your code, referencing it will generate a warning and run the following query:

```
UPDATE admin SET first_name='Rajendra', last_name='Arora' WHERE id=''
```

You need to set `$id` somewhere.

Also be aware of SQL injection depending on where this value is coming from, if it is from user input it needs to either be casted to an integer or escaped if it is a string.

If it is an integer you need not include quotes around it (`WHERE id=1` as opposed to `WHERE id='1'`).

Comment: so how to make `$id` variable please help!!

Comment: In the same way you set any variable: `$id = 1;`

Comment: but i want to make it through using `$id` i'm working for a small project where it will fetch from database using `$id'...

Comment: I don't really understand - your code shows you echoing out every entry in the admin table and then after this running an update on some undefined $id. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

First your ID should be set and second your ID is probably not a string (varchar, char or text) in the database. It would be and should be numeric. In that the case, don't wrap the id in ''. Only string data should be wrapped in ''.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,Remove single quotes

```
// Assign ID here 
$id= 1;
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE admin SET first_name='Rajendra', last_name='Arora' WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: because you have to define id

Answer (score 0):

Define `$id` and then something like this should work:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE admin SET first_name='Rajendra', last_name='Arora' WHERE id=?")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

If `$id` comes from a `$_GET`  or `$_POST` variable, be sure to never embed it in a query directly!